# Hard Drive Partition

Tags: partitioning

I partitioned my hard drive like this:
250GB = root
750GB = logical

I am already using now the 250GB, now I want to use my 750GB for a file server. I am planning to configure samba file server to my system. Can someone help me what to do?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's nothing you really need to do. You can make a symlink to your 750GB partition and use that for your file server.

Comment: @ nikhil . Maybe you should explain "How to" do what you suggest step by step in an answer. It could be useful for others also

Answer (score 0):

How will it be used? By Windows PCs? Or Linux users on the Ubuntu system? There is a lot of information about samba online. Check out the [Quick Start Guide](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/FastStart.html).